# Parsing JSON with react native, looping through

Tags: json, react-native

i am trying to parse a json file by displaying all the names in the clubs
the json file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2017-18/it.1.clubs.json

my current code i have is

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        dataSource: null,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2017-18/it.1.clubs.json')
        .then ( (response) => response.json() )
        .then ( (responseJson) => {

          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson.clubs,
          })
        })

        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
}

 render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.containter}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
    )

  } else {
        return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.dataSource.name}</Text>
        </View>
        )
```

I just want to loop through to display all the names in the clubs

Comment: You need to iterate over the clubs array to show the names of each clubs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Couple of edits**: Changing the `initial state` of dataSouce value as an `array`, this is to ensure it doesn't throw `can't read property map of undefined`. 
You don't need to return the `fetch` call, because you don't need a `promise` to returned.

**EDIT:** Added a loading text before all the clubs are loaded.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    dataSource: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => {
      fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2017-18/it.1.clubs.json"
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          console.log(responseJson);
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson.clubs
          });
        })

        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Club Names</h1>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <h1>Loading Clubs...</h1>
        ) : (
          this.state.dataSource.map(data => <h2 key={data.key}>{data.name}</h2>)
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Sandbox Link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dream-7lpcm?fontsize=14